# rndc: error: /etc/bind/rndc.key:5: unknown option 'options' .. could not load rndc configuration

Tags: linux, dns, ubuntu-12.04, bind

I am working on my Bsc thesis which talks about the DNS-based authentication of named entities (DANE).. In order to set up DANE records, I first need to set up a simple BIND server (later installing DNSSEC..). I am new to Linux, so detailed help is much appreciated :)

I installed BIND9 on Ubuntu 12.04. Configured the "named.conf.options", "named.conf.local" and the "rndc.key". However, when I attempt to restart bind (using the command: `/etc/init.d/bind9 restart`) I get the following error:

```
  root@ubuntu:/etc/bind# /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
     * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                                                                                       
rndc: error: /etc/bind/rndc.key:5: unknown option 'options'
    rndc: could not load rndc configuration
                                                                                                                             [ OK ]
     * Starting domain name service... bind9                                                                                       [fail] 
    root@ubuntu:
```

I have also followed this tutorial (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543750), and the command: `tail /var/log/daemon | grep named` , for analysing logs, is not working for me!

This is my named.conf file:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";
key "rndc-key" {
       algorithm hmac-md5;
       secret "2mPij4Zk4JSh0KKUZPPEgA==";
};
controls {
       inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
       allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};
```

This is my rndc.key file:

```
key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "2mPij4Zk4JSh0KKUZPPEgA==";
};
options {
        default-key "rndc-key";
        default-server 127.0.0.1;
        default-port 953;
};
# End of rndc.conf
# Use with the following in named.conf, adjusting the allow list as needed:
# key "rndc-key" {
#       algorithm hmac-md5;
#       secret "2mPij4Zk4JSh0KKUZPPEgA==";
# };
#
# controls {
#       inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
#       allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
# };
# End of named.conf
```

This is my zone settings:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400 ; 1 day

danetest.com. IN SOA srv1.danetest.com. hostmaster.danetest.com. (
        2014010307 ; serial
        8H ; refresh
        4H ; retry;
        25W ; expire
        1D ; minimum
)

danetest.com. IN NS srv1.danetest.com.

$ORIGIN danetest.com.

localhost IN A 127.0.0.1

daneverified IN A 192.168.1.101
danebroken   IN A 192.168.1.101
```

Your help is much appreciated!!! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

`rndc.key` should not contain anything but the key.  You can then include this in `/etc/bind/rndc.conf` for rndc and somewhere in `/etc/bind/named.conf` or its includes.  I've got a working config that does this at https://github.com/chicks-net/dns-cache-performance/tree/master/configs/bind which took some finagling.  There's a `Makefile` in there for generating the `rndc.key`, but you have to clean up out the 'bogus' options by hand.